# DevCenter package submission error

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I just completed my very first very own Windows Store app, so I am trying to submit it on Windows Store. I followed guidelines but problem everytime occurs after uploading package. Package is uploaded, analyzed and "error" is shown. But nothing more. WACK test is OK. Is there way how to know, what is wrong with the packages?

[image]

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Sometimes the Store has issues with Chrome or other browsers, so try using IE, maybe it helps.

Comment: Yea, IE, and judging by Resume, it probably didn't finish the upload.

Comment: @thewindev it worked I feel like rookie now... anyway, write it down as answer please and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the Store has issues with Chrome or other browsers, so try using IE, maybe it helps.